# Running sql server service on domain user account

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, domain

I am trying to change the account of sql server service from LocalSystem to a domain user account. It is giving me an error "No mapping between account names and security IDs was done"

The server is an additional domain controller in the network. Before changing the service account to domain user I have created the domain user login from windows in sql server. Can someone please help?

Comment: Are you using the services control panel to change the account, or the SQL Server Configuration Manager?  It is recommended that you not run SQL Server on a domain controller.

Comment: I am using SQL Server Configuration Manager to change the account. The sql server I am installing will just server as a witness in a mirroring setup.

Comment: Did you install SQL, then promote the machine to being a domain controller? This MSKB may apply. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2019402

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @mrdenny. Sql server was pre existing on the the server and later the server was made as an additional domain controller. Doing a fresh installation of sql server fixed my problem. I had to use this workaround to uninstall sql server instance http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925976

Sql server was serving as a witness so I didn't have any problem for a fresh installation. But it is recommended not to run SQL Server on domain controller.